# issues finding a string in a text file python

Tags: python

I have a python program that is supposed to search a text file for an ID. If the Id doesn't exist in the file then the program will write it to the file.

```py
path = "M:\\Program\\files\\"
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))]
for x in range(0, len(files)):
    file = files[x]
    file = file.split('`')
    postid = file[0]
    print(postid)
    with open('postid.txt', 'r+') as f:
            if postid in f:
                print('already used')
            else:
                print('not used')
                f.write(postid + '\r')
```

The code always returns that the string isn't in the file when It is. I have tried different methods of scanning the file such as using a for loop and examining each line but they haven't worked. I feel like I am missing some small detail but I cant find what I have done wrong.

The file looks like

```
1k2kk
302kk
2ll3d
2ll32
33lld
ect..
```

EDIT:
Never found out why the code wasn't working. I tried every suggestion but nothing worked. Finally gave up trying to read directly from the file and just had the program dump the file into a list and search the list for the ID instead of the file. I know this is not ideal but the ID file will probably not be very big when using the program so hopefully this will not cause issues.

Comment: can you show the attempt where you iterate over every line, since that should solve your problem

Comment: A sample file would also help.

Comment: @aws_apprentice The line by line code was pretty much identical  to what Micheal posted below.

Comment: `a+` opens for reading and appending. [What's the difference between 'r+' and 'a+' when open file in python?](//stackoverflow.com/a/13248062)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You need to search the file line by line (or chunk by chunk but line by line is easiest):

```py
with open('postid.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if postid in line:
            print("already used")
            break
    else:
        print("not used")
        f.write(postid + '\r')
```

Comment: the `exists` variable is overkill

Comment: Depending on the structure of the rest of the program, it may not be, and I don't want to make assumptions.

Comment: Don’t use readlines just for iteration! It needlessly loads the entire file into memory.

Comment: Te entire variable + if-else block pattern is unnecessary. Put the if body into the loop, and the else body into the omitted  for-else.

Answer (score 0):

Try a+ as the access mode.

```
with open('postid.txt', 'a+') as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code, although I'm not sure how to name some of the variables.

```py
for curr_str in files:
    postid = curr_str.split('`')[0]
    print(postid)
    with open('postid.txt', 'a+') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip()
            if postid == line:
                print('found')
                break
        else:
            print('not found')
            f.write(postid)
```

Comment: if postid == line: is wrong. Should be if postid in line:

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola How come? What I understood from OP's post is that each of the values in the text file is a single ID.

Comment: line would have the '\n' char as well if you have not stripped it.

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola Good point, can't believe I forgot that. Thanks!